# Wrapping a BlockFeature in Draftail (Wagtail Rich Text Editor)

Tags: javascript, django, wagtail, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I am stuck at a problem. Maybe someone of you does have an Idea.
The Problem looks like following:
We have in Wagtail for the Draftail Editor 2 possible Features.
Which are BlockFeature and InlineStyleFeature.

But what, if you want to add a Feature in the Rich Text Editor, which should wrap an BlockFeature?

As example:
H1,H2,H3 etc. are BlockFeatures.
I have done an custom Feature which will highlight stuff with an border, i did that with the InlineStyleFeature.

So, this works properly on normal plaintext.
But when you are adding some BlockFeatures like a H1 or a H2 the InputStyleFeature will automatically wrap inside the other Block Features.

Example:

Without Border:

`Some Plain Text <h1> Test </h1>`

With Border:

`<border> Some Plain Text <h1><border> Test </border> </h1> </border>`

The thing i want to accomplish is a simple :

`<border> Some Plain Text <h1> Test </h1> </border>`

When i am using a Border as a BlockFeature, the Headline Tags and all other BlockFeatures will be gone logically.

So.. my question is :

Is there any way to accomplish something like that ?
Does anyone has experience with that kind of stuff?
I would be happy if someone could help me.

Greetings

Comment: Have you considered building this with StreamField, rather than inside rich text? https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html

Comment: Yes, i have done that. but it would be better, to achive this in the rich text editor. there has to be a way somehow, but i have not figured it out yet :/